# Is It possible to make tabs without using fragments, view pager and ActionBar in android

Tags: android, android-tabs

I want to make layout in which my header and footer will be static and middle view will change on click event of buttons in footer. I have achieved this using view flipper. Also I have done same using ActionBar tabs with view pager and fragments

But I want some other alternative

Comment: Of course, you can always do it the bad old way by creating views for the tabs and swapping out data on your own.  But why do it the hard way?

Comment: yes it is possible but i would not recommend that.